# Xcode: Mute (suppress) "Update to recommended settings" warning

Tags: xcode

We all know this message, and it is pretty annoying if you have a reason to have different settings.

How can I suppress this warning?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps on this page worked for me:

https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/validate-project-settings-never.html

Credit to Jeff :)